# Maximum of all distances between any pairs of vertices of a random triangle

Tags: list-manipulation, random, distributions, map, maximum

Given a set $S_n$ of $n$ points selected uniformly at random in a $d$-ball, I want to estimate the average length of the longest side of a triangle having as vertices any three distinct points of $S_n$, when $n\gg d\gg 1$. Below you can find my approach, which unfortunately does not scale well with the number of points $n$ nor the number of dimensions $d$. Is it possible to improve it to make it more scalable?

```
n:=300; d:=30;
p := RandomPoint[Sphere[d], {n}];
x:=EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[p, {3}][[1 ;; , 1 ;; 2]]; 
y:=EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[p, {3}][[1 ;; , 2 ;; 3]]; 
z:=EuclideanDistance @@@ Drop[Subsets[p, {3}], None, {2}];
Mean[Map[Max, Transpose[{x,y,z}]]]
```

Comment: maybe `n := 300; d := 30;
p := RandomPoint[Sphere[d], {n/3, 3}];
xyz := Apply[EuclideanDistance, Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ p, {2}];
Mean[Map[Max, Transpose[xyz]]]`?

Comment: Thank you @kglr ! Why is your approach so fast compare to mine? I am new to Wolfram Language. What is the most significant difference?

Comment: Penelope, it is faster because it is not correct:)

Comment: @kglr there is something wrong in my approach too: I am now realizing that the points are selected from a sphere, i.e., the *surface of a ball*. For instance, if $d=1$ the points are represented by only one coordinate selected from $\{−1,1\}$ (instead of being selected from $[−1,1]$), i.e. the *boundary* of $[−1,1]$.  Why do we get a value approaching $2$ when $d=1$ as $n$ increases? I would expect to obtain a value approaching $3/2$ as $n$ increases, when the points are selected uniformly at random from $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: Yes,you need `Ball[]`

Comment: Thank you @cvgmt . OK, this solves the issue about "ball vs. sphere". But why, for $d=1$, when the points are selected uniformly at random from $\{-1,1\}$ (`Sphere[]` case), do I get a value very close to $7/8$ (and with kglr's approach one gets $2$) whereas the asymptotic result as $n$ increases must be $3/2$? I do not understand what is *wrong* in these approaches (both).

Comment: since you defined `p`, `x`, `y` and `z` with `SetDelayed`, `p` is reevaluated every time it appears in `x` (similarly for `y` and `z`) . That is, a different `p` is used when you get `x`, `y` and `z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 300; d = 30; 
p = RandomPoint[Sphere[d], {n, 3}]; 
xyz =  Apply[EuclideanDistance, Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ p, {2}];

Mean[Map[Max, xyz]]
```

> ```
> 1.5164
> ```

If we use `Ball[d]` instead of `Sphere[d]` we get `1.47179`.

And a modification of your code (eliminating repeated invocations of `Subsets[#,3]` on `p`):

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 300; d = 30;
p = RandomPoint[Sphere[d], {n}];
xyz = With[{s3 = Subsets[p, {3}]}, 
   Apply[EuclideanDistance, Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ s3, {2}]];
Mean[Map[Max, xyz]]
```

> ```
> 1.51594
> ```

If we replace `Sphere[d]` with `Ball[d]` we get `1.46985`.

Comment: Thank you a lot @kglr !

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Seems no so effective.

Here we use `RandomPoint` to select uniform points in `Ball[]` and use `RandomSample` to select three points to construct a random triangle.

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 300;
d = 30;
pts = RandomPoint[Ball[d], n];
Table[Max @@ 
   EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets [RandomSample[pts, 3], {2}], {i, 
   200000}] // Mean
```

> `1.46926`

Comment: Thank you very much @cvgmt ! This approach seems to be really fast!

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati Thanks your vote up！

Comment: You are welcome! Why did you replace `RandomChoice` by `RandomSample`?

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati  since `RandomSample` select three distinguish points and `RandomChoice` cannot. Perhaps we also need to find a way to avoid co-line and select the real triangles.

Comment: I see, thank you!